# Will Ubuntu fix my Video Card Driver issue?

Tags: upgrade, gpu-driver

Will Ubuntu work on a Dell Inspirion 1300 Netbook currently running Windows XP?  I've tried install Windows 7 Ultimate and it's not working properly due to the video card driver issue. The Celeron processor is so old that even  a custom driver for it doesn't do the job. Can't see even  a simple Youtube video. Will Ubuntu work on my system, and fix the problem with the video card? Or I should try it first and let you know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

You can install either Xubuntu or Lubuntu on your Dell Inspiron 1300. Preferably Xubuntu because Lubuntu doesn't have a Long Term Support release. Preferably Xubuntu 12.04 because it is a Long Term Support release which is supported by updates until April, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs from Dell, your best bet would be [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/).  Whichever one you choose, I recommend that once you create a bootable CD/DVD or USB flash, is to try befor you install, that way you'll get an idea if it will work OK with your hardware, and once everything is OK, you can go ahead and install.

Comment: I suggest Lubuntu, it's very light weight.

Answer (score -1):

Linux Drivers are different than MS Windows so try downloading a disc image to a DVD/ USB Thumbdrive. Just boot from it and try to see if you can install from there.